# SQL Server Renaming Tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm switching contents of my tables by renaming them so the latest data goes to the main table. Does it automatically include the indexes on both tables as well?

```
EXEC sp_rename 'MAIN', 'TMP';
EXEC sp_rename 'LATEST', 'MAIN';
EXEC sp_rename 'TMP', 'LATEST';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every table has an `object_id` and the name it is known by is just an attribute of that object. You could see each of the tables from your question listed in the [`sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view with a query like this:

```
select *
from db_nm.sys.objects as o
where o.name in ('MAIN', 'TMP', 'LATEST')
and o.type = 'U' --filtering to (user-defined) Tables only
```

Each index, listed in the [`sys.indexes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view, shows two IDs. The first is the `index_id` which is the ID of the index itself, and the `object_id` which is the ID of the object being indexed.

This means that when you use `sp_rename` to change the name of the table, the only thing that happens is the `name` attribute of the object is updated, and none of the ID numbers are being changed.

In other words, if `index_a` was pointing to object 123456 before renaming the table, it will still point to that object afterwards.

**Update:**

You can verify the table / index setup by using the query below which will return one record for each table / index combination.

```
select s.name as schema_nm
, o.name as table_nm
, i.name as index_nm
from db_nm.sys.objects as o
inner join db_nm.sys.schemas as s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
left join db_nm.sys.indexes as i on o.object_id = i.object_id
where o.type = 'U'
and o.name in ('MAIN', 'TMP', 'LATEST')
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: So can I say that i could just leave the indexes as is as they will still be pointing to their respective tables even when renamed?

Comment: Yes, any indexes on table `MAIN` before running the code from your question will be on the table named `TMP` afterwards.